# select2 Results Wrapper

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for a project and have a need to break out the results that are selected (from a multiple select box) into smaller items "below" the input (example below):

[image: Multiple selections]

I've looked into `formatSelection`, but the main issue I'm having is how I'd move the input field to be on it's own, instead of being appended onto the end of `select2-choices`, which I have yet to find any options for. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar to handle selecting multiple options in narrow text boxes.  fortunately you have control over the formatting of selected items.  Here's what i used to show just how the first letter of a yes or no choice. you could modify this function to create your external tags and return a blank response to not show the choice in the select2 container.  though you'd also have to hook the choice deleted event to stay in sync.

$opts = {
    ...
    formatSelection: select2YesNoFormat,
    ....
    }

```
function select2YesNoFormat(item) {
    var originalText   = item.text;
    return '<span class="select2-tag" title="' + originalText + '">' + originalText.substring(0,1) + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks - was hoping for something that didn't involve another "sync" like you mentioned, but do appreciate you going over that.

Comment: ends up select2 fires a select2-removed event when an option is deleted so it should be easy to stay in 'sync'